# How to revert Galaxy S8+ to stock firmware?

Tags: unbricking, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-s-8

Is it possible to revert Samsung Galaxy S8+ to stock firmware? The phone was interrupted while upgrading the software and is now bricked. 
The model is SM-G955P